# Entry widget - pass input to onValidate method within same class

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

I have a class which creates a frame with entry widgets for minutes and seconds. The separate onValidate method within the class will be used to validate input to the entry widgets, but initially I just want to output the results of all the available substitution codes (%P, %S etc).
I'm currently getting the error:
**AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'text'**

Below is the full code that gives me the error.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.create_frame_main().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)    

    def create_frame_main(self):
        self.frame_main = tk.Frame(self)

        self.mins_var = tk.IntVar()
        self.secs_var = tk.IntVar()

        vcmd = (self.register(self.onValidate), '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W') 

        self.frame_time_input = tk.Frame(self.frame_main)
        self.frame_time_input.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.entry_mins = tk.Entry(self.frame_time_input, validate="key", textvariable=self.mins_var, validatecommand=vcmd, width=5)
                
        self.entry_mins.pack(side='left')
        self.label_mins = tk.Label(self.frame_time_input, text='mins')
        self.label_mins.pack(side='left')
        
        self.entry_secs = tk.Entry(self.frame_time_input, validate="key", textvariable=self.secs_var, validatecommand=vcmd, width=3)
                
        self.entry_secs.pack(side="left")
        self.label_secs = tk.Label(self.frame_time_input, text='secs')
        self.label_secs.pack(side='left')

        self.text = tk.Text(self.frame_main, height=10, width=40)
        self.text.grid(row=1,column=0)

        return self.frame_main
    
    def onValidate(self, d, i, P, s, S, v, V, W):
        self.text.delete("1.0", "end")   # delete everything currently in the text box
        self.text.insert("end","OnValidate:\n")
        self.text.insert("end","d='%s'\n" % d)
        self.text.insert("end","i='%s'\n" % i)
        self.text.insert("end","P='%s'\n" % P)
        self.text.insert("end","s='%s'\n" % s)
        self.text.insert("end","S='%s'\n" % S)
        self.text.insert("end","v='%s'\n" % v)
        self.text.insert("end","V='%s'\n" % V)
        self.text.insert("end","W='%s'\n" % W)
```

I think I'm getting the error because the self.text widget defined in the constructor method is not being passed onto the onValidate method but not sure exactly how. The error does not occur if I no longer make the onValidate method part of the runtime by making the following changes:

```
#vcmd = (self.register(self.onValidate), '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')    

#self.entry_mins = tk.Entry(self.frame_time_input, validate="key", textvariable=self.mins_var, validatecommand=vcmd, width=5)
self.entry_mins = tk.Entry(self.frame_time_input, textvariable=self.mins_var, width=5)
#self.entry_secs = tk.Entry(self.frame_time_input, validate="key", textvariable=self.secs_var, validatecommand=vcmd, width=3)
self.entry_secs = tk.Entry(self.frame_time_input, textvariable=self.secs_var, width=3)
```

Traceback:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\PythonPrograms\entry_val_class.py", line 39, in onValidate
    self.text.delete("1.0", "end")   # delete everything currently in the text box
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2383, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The initial goal is to ensure that whenever the user tries to edit the minutes or seconds entry widgets, the onValidate method successfully outputs the results of the various substitution codes from that input to the text widget (as defined in the 'self.text.insert' lines).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: Thanks for the reply MattDMo. Have added tracebacks

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that your validation is being called when you create the widget, and this happens before you define `self.text`. Since the validation command calls `self.text.delete`, you get the error since `self.text` doesn't yet exist.

If you move the definition of `self.text` up, the problem goes away.

Also, your `onValidate` must always return either `True` or `False`. Otherwise it will cause validation to be turned off the first time that the function is run.

Comment: Ah I think I know what you mean now - define the "self.text - tk. Text" line above the first "self.entry_minus = tk.Entry" line that calls validatecommand=vcmd (which in turn calls onValidate)?